# How do you get the IP address from a request in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip-address

I have been trying to figure this out but cannot find a reliable way to get a clients IP address when making a request to a page in asp.net that works with all servers.

Comment: This question has been asked before. Check these links out:- - [How to get user client ip address in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-user-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) - [Browser IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756067/browser-ip-address) HTH. (vote to close this).

Answer (score 38):

One method is to use Request object:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl1.Text = Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
 IpAddress=HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

To access an index or property on C#, you should use [ ] instead of ( )

Comment: Non-invocable member 'System.Web.HttpRequest.ServerVariables' cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public static string GetIpAddress()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current != null ? HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress : "";
    }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a little better rather than just putting in code. Try to explain why you answered this way.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress this contains our Ip address for this first of all we have to check HttpContext.Current is null or not

Comment: use this code in code behind of Asp.net

           
public static string GetIpAddress()
            {
                return HttpContext.Current != null ? 
    HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress : "";
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: You might want to explain why this answer is better than the ones that were already given (in 2009 and 2015)

Comment: @HansKesting it's full reference. It's not an answer for questioner, But for anyone else needs it today

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var IpAddress = Request.Headers["Referer"][0];
```

Comment: Please consider adding a bit of description to your question or perhaps a link to the documentation for this. This will help this answer be more complete and helpful further into the future.

Answer (score 0):

If there are proxies between client and server. **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** header can be used.

```
var ips = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
var clientIp = "";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ips))
{
    string[] addresses = ips.Split(',');
    if (addresses.Length != 0)
    {
        clientIp = addresses[0];
    }
}
else
{
    clientIp = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpContext with property bellow:

```
var _request1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        string requestedDomain = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
        string requestScheme = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme;
        string requestQueryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["QUERY_STRING"];
        string requestUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["URL"];
```