# How to detect OS device and IP (ASP.NET C#)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to develope a small ASP.NET app in C#. It's need some function and main function in this app is

> Detected OS device
>
> Detected IP that visit my app

Example: When i'm using Iphone and visit my app with USA IP, my app alert (Javascript alert) in my browser:

> OS: IOS - IP: 1x.xxx.xxxx => USA

Sorry for my poor in English, i try the best to show you my idea. Thank for your Helping !!!

Comment: Browser detection using C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221722/browser-detection

Comment: IP adress http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866980/how-do-you-get-the-ip-address-from-a-request-in-asp-net

Comment: to get the country from IP use this API http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. Browser detection using C# with your link can detect OS (IOS or Android or Window) right?

Comment: Thank you, you save my time so much !!!